# How do I print the url path without parameters?

Tags: go, gorilla

I have a RESTful API using Gorilla/mux. It is parameterized in the path. I am creating it as such:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
subr := r.PathPrefix("/v1").Subrouter()
subr.Handle("/organizations/{orgId}/projects/{projectId}", CreateProject()).Methods(http.MethodPost)
```

However, when capturing the request and logging the outcome, I don't want to log i.e.

`/organizations/fff-555-aaa9999/projects/amazing-project`

which is what I'd get from parsing the `r *http.Request.URL` value.

Instead, I'd like to get the initial router value of `/organizations/{orgId}/projects/{projectId}` so I can filter from *that* in my logging.

Using gorilla/mux, is there a way to get the router path without the actual parameters, but the parameter variables instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `CreateProject` function you coud use this:

```
func CreateProject(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path, _ := mux.CurrentRoute(r).GetPathTemplate()
    fmt.Println(path)
}
```